# Growing potatoes in delayed sequences

Tags: c#, inheritance, iterator, fibonacci-sequence

In order to grow potatoes I'm implementing the retry pattern. If I fail to grow them, I'd like to try it again later. The first part I've implemented is a collection of delay generators.

Their base type is the `DelaySequence`:

```
public abstract class DelaySequence : IEnumerable<TimeSpan>
{
    protected DelaySequence(int count) { Count = count; }

    public int Count { get; }

    public IEnumerator<TimeSpan> GetEnumerator() => Generate().Take(Count).GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    protected abstract IEnumerable<TimeSpan> Generate();
}
```

I derived three concrete generators from it.

One regular:

```
public class RegularDelaySequence : DelaySequence
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _delay;
    public RegularDelaySequence(TimeSpan delay, int count) : base(count) { _delay = delay; }
    protected override IEnumerable<TimeSpan> Generate()
    {
        while (true) yield return _delay;
    }
}
```

and two irregular:

```
public abstract class IrregularDelaySequence : DelaySequence
{
    protected IrregularDelaySequence(int count) : base(count) { }
}

public class FibonacciDelaySequence : IrregularDelaySequence
{
    private readonly Queue<TimeSpan> _lastPair;
    public FibonacciDelaySequence(TimeSpan firstTwo, TimeSpan firstStep, int count) : base(count)
    {
        _lastPair = new Queue<TimeSpan>(new[]
        {
            firstTwo,
            firstTwo,
            firstTwo + firstStep,
        });
    }
    protected override IEnumerable<TimeSpan> Generate()
    {
        foreach (var delay in _lastPair)
        {
            yield return delay;
        }

        _lastPair.Dequeue();

        while (true)
        {
            var current = _lastPair.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (sum, next) => sum + next);
            yield return current;
            _lastPair.Enqueue(current);
            _lastPair.Dequeue();
        };
    }
}

public class GeometricDelaySequence : IrregularDelaySequence
{
    private TimeSpan _current;
    private readonly Func<TimeSpan, TimeSpan> _increment;
    public GeometricDelaySequence(TimeSpan first, Func<TimeSpan, TimeSpan> increment, int count) : base(count)
    {
        _current  = first;
        _increment = increment;
    }
    protected override IEnumerable<TimeSpan> Generate()
    {
        yield return _current;

        while (true)
        {
            yield return (_current = _increment(_current));
        };
    }
}
```

Their usage is very simple. Create an instance, specify the parameters and you're ready to go:

```
new RegularDelaySequence(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 7).Dump();
new FibonacciDelaySequence(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 7).Dump();
new GeometricDelaySequence(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), ts => ts + ts, 7).Dump();
```

*`Dump()` is LINQPad's method*

Results:

*RegularDelaySequence*

```
00:00:01 
00:00:01 
00:00:01 
00:00:01 
00:00:01 
00:00:01 
00:00:01
```

*FibonacciDelaySequence*

```
00:00:01 
00:00:01 
00:00:04 
00:00:05 
00:00:09 
00:00:14 
00:00:23
```

*GeometricDelaySequence*

```
00:00:01 
00:00:02 
00:00:04 
00:00:08 
00:00:16 
00:00:32 
00:01:04
```

Comment: LOL I got downvoted. Someone doesn't like potatoes ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### IrregularDelaySequence

I don't think the base `IrregularDelaySequence` class is needed here since it doesn't contain any members. To check if a specified instance is an irregular sequence, you could just compare its type to the `RegularDelaySequence`. If the type isn't `RegularDelaySequence`, the sequence is definitly irregular.

### FibonacciDelaySequence

The logic of this class isn't quite clear for me.
I'd prefer to use an "oldschool" variables instead of the `Queue`:

```
public class FibonacciDelaySequence : DelaySequence
{
    private TimeSpan _prev;
    private TimeSpan _cur;

    public FibonacciDelaySequence(TimeSpan firstTwo, TimeSpan firstStep, int count) : base(count)
    {
        _prev = firstTwo;
        _cur = _prev + firstStep;
    }
    protected override IEnumerable<TimeSpan> Generate()
    {
        yield return _prev;
        yield return _prev;
        yield return _cur;

        while (true)
        {
            var current = _prev + _cur;
            yield return current;
            _prev = _cur;
            _cur = current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I must admint the _oldschool_ variables look much nicer then my over-engineered queue ;-]