# Try again, and again, and again... but not too often because the potatoes won't grow

Tags: c#, design-patterns, error-handling, inheritance, async-await

The [delay sequence](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146637/growing-potatoes-in-delayed-sequences/146641) has been fixed so I can move to the next step which are the `Retry` and `Breaker`.

(Just ignore the console output here and there. There is no logging yet so it helps me to see what's going on in LINQPad).

Both are derived from a common type `Try`:

```
public abstract class Try
{
    public abstract bool Execute(Action action, Action<AttemptInfo> onException)

    public virtual bool Execute(Action action)
    {
        return Execute(action, ex => { });
    }

    public abstract Task<bool> ExecuteAsync(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action<AttemptInfo> onException);

    public Task<bool> ExecuteAsync(Action action)
    {
        return ExecuteAsync(action, CancellationToken.None, ex => { });
    }
}
```

The `Retry` provides some additional fields about the state and provides feedback to the calling method via the `AttemptInfo` type.

```
public class AttemptInfo
{
    internal AttemptInfo(Exception exception, int count)
    {
        Exception = exception;
        Count = count;
    }

    public Exception Exception { get; }

    public int Count { get; }

    public bool Handled { get; set; }
}

public class Retry : Try
{
    private readonly DelaySequence _delaySequence;

    private readonly List<Exception> _exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    public IEnumerable<Exception> Exceptions => _exceptions.AsReadOnly();

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public Retry(DelaySequence delaySequence)
    {
        _delaySequence = delaySequence;
    }

    public override bool Execute(Action action, Action<AttemptInfo> onException)
    {
        foreach (var delay in _delaySequence)
        {
            try
            {
                Count++;
                action();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _exceptions.Add(ex);
                var attempt = new AttemptInfo(ex, Count);
                onException(attempt);
                if (!attempt.Handled) { throw; }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override async Task<bool> ExecuteAsync(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action<AttemptInfo> onException)
    {
        foreach (var delay in _delaySequence)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            try
            {
                Count++;
                action();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _exceptions.Add(ex);
                var attempt = new AttemptInfo(ex, Count);
                onException(attempt);
                if (!attempt.Handled) { throw; }
            }
            await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `Breaker` acts as a decorator for the `Retry`.

```
public class Breaker : Try
{
    private readonly Retry _retry;

    public Breaker(Retry retry, BreakerThreshold threshold)
    {
        _retry = retry;
        Threshold = threshold;
    }

    public BreakerThreshold Threshold { get; }

    public DateTime? LastExceptionOn { get; private set; }

    public int ExceptionCount { get; private set; }

    public BreakerState State { get; private set; }

    private void Reset()
    {
        LastExceptionOn = null;
        ExceptionCount = 0;
        State = BreakerState.Closed;
    }

    public override bool Execute(Action action, Action<AttemptInfo> onException)
    {
        return _retry.Execute(() =>
        {
            var hasOpenTimedout = (DateTime.UtcNow - LastExceptionOn) > Threshold.Timeout;
            if (Threshold.HasTimedout(LastExceptionOn))
            {
                Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("You may try again.");
            }

            if (State == BreakerState.Closed)
            {
                action();
            }
        }, attempt =>
        {
            if (Threshold.Exceeded(LastExceptionOn, ExceptionCount))
            {
                State = BreakerState.Open;
                attempt.Handled = true;
                Console.WriteLine("It's enough for now!" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                return;
            }

            LastExceptionOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ExceptionCount++;

            onException(attempt);
        });
    }

    public override async Task<bool> ExecuteAsync(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action<AttemptInfo> onException)
    {
        return await _retry.ExecuteAsync(() =>
        {
            var hasOpenTimedout = (DateTime.UtcNow - LastExceptionOn) > Threshold.Timeout;
            if (hasOpenTimedout)
            {
                Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("You may try to dig again.");
            }

            if (State == BreakerState.Closed)
            {
                action();
            }
        }, cancellationToken, attempt =>
        {
            if (Threshold.Exceeded(LastExceptionOn, ExceptionCount))
            {
                State = BreakerState.Open;
                attempt.Handled = true;
                Console.WriteLine("It's enough!" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                return;
            }

            LastExceptionOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ExceptionCount++;

            onException(attempt);
        });
    }
}
```

It's supported by two *helper* types:

```
public enum BreakerState
{
    Closed,
    Open,
    //HalfOpen, // I didn't find any use for this yet.
}

public class BreakerThreshold
{
    public BreakerThreshold(int maxExceptionCount, TimeSpan timespan, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        MaxExceptionCount = maxExceptionCount;
        TimeSpan = TimeSpan;
        Timeout = timeout;
    }

    public int MaxExceptionCount { get; }

    public TimeSpan TimeSpan { get; }

    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; }

    public bool Exceeded(DateTime? exceptionOn, int count)
    {
        return
            exceptionOn.HasValue &&
            DateTime.UtcNow - exceptionOn > TimeSpan &&
            count > MaxExceptionCount;
    }

    public bool HasTimedout(DateTime? exceptionOn)
    {
        return (DateTime.UtcNow - exceptionOn) > Timeout;
    }   
}
```

Usage example:

```
var counter = 0;

var failingAction = new Action(() =>
{
    if (counter++ < 6)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Plant potato! Attempt {counter}");
        throw new Exception("Soil too hard to dig!");
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Finally planted! Attempt: {counter}");
});


var retry = new Retry(new RegularDelaySequence(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), 30));
var breaker = new Breaker(retry, new BreakerThreshold(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));

breaker.Execute(failingAction, attempt =>
{
    attempt.Handled = true;
});
// Wait for the breaker to timeout.
Thread.Sleep(3200);
breaker.Execute(failingAction, attempt =>
{
    attempt.Handled = true;
});
```

Output:

```
Plant potato! Attempt 1
Soil too hard to dig!
Plant potato! Attempt 2
Soil too hard to dig!
Plant potato! Attempt 3
Soil too hard to dig!
Plant potato! Attempt 4
It's enough for now!
You may try again.
Plant potato! Attempt 5
Soil too hard to dig!
Plant potato! Attempt 6
Soil too hard to dig!
Finally planted! Attempt: 7
```

What I particularly don't like are the 99% identical loops in the sync and async APIs. They differ only by the wait and by the `async` keyword.

Oh, and one more thing. I know there is something like Polly but I like to have things my way besides it helped me to understand a few things already so it's a good exercise at the same time.

Comment: Are you doing this just to learn or why not use The Transient Fault Handling Application Block?

Comment: @CharlesNRice because the Enterprise Library has not been developed for many years and it crashes all over the place. Just thinking of the logging block, never again ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t I've only used Unity and the Transient Fault Handling Block and have never had issues with either.

Comment: @t3chb0t Re: methods being 99% identical, can't you just extract the try/catch bit, which seems identical, into its own method, and call that method from sync/async `Execute` methods? Like that you also separate the "execute" logic from the "what to do before/after execute" logic.

Comment: @eurotrash this acutally makes sense. I don't know why I was thinking about the entire loops the whole time.

Comment: @eurotrash if you post it as an answer you'll get some rep ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t Well when you put it like that... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of some code duplication by extracting the try/catch block in the Execute methods to a new method:

```
private bool ExecuteAction(Action action, Action<AttemptInfo> onException)
{
    try
    {
        Count++;
        action();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _exceptions.Add(ex);
        var attempt = new AttemptInfo(ex, Count);
        onException(attempt);
        if (!attempt.Handled) { throw; }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then both Execute methods can call this method instead:

```
public override bool Execute(Action action, Action<AttemptInfo> onException)
{
    foreach (var delay in _delaySequence)
    {
        if (ExecuteAction(action, onException))
            return true;

        Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
    return false;
}

public override async Task<bool> ExecuteAsync(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action<AttemptInfo> onException)
{
    foreach (var delay in _delaySequence)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        if (ExecuteAction(action, onException))
            return true;

        await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
    }
    return false;
}
```

(I wish I could just call it in a single line and it either returns a value or throws an exception, but you only return the result if it's `true`.)

Now the rest of the duplication becomes more obvious - I'd like to extract the loop and final `return false` to a new method that takes two more delegates - one as a pre-execution action (`cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` for the async method, nothing for the sync method) and one for the post-execution action (`Thread.Sleep(delay)`, `await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken)`). Each public method would then call that private method with four delegate parameters, and the entirety of the loop/execution could be in one method. But as my C# knowledge is really based on 4.0, I don't know enough about async/await to know whether that's feasible.

Comment: I must say it would be perfect if I could only have one method that does the job for sync and async but I'm not that good with this stuff so I need to keep them both. But what I can implement is generic version of the `ExecuteX` that returns something. I return a `bool` because I didn't want to have another `try/catch` around this. I wanted the `Retry` to handle _everything_ for me.